# Project Reactor - the usage of defer() to make method retry-able

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Recently I tried to test the retry behaviour in unit tests by setting up the mocked dependency to return multiple Mono.error() before returning a successful mono.just() at the end:

```java
@Mock
Dependency dependency;

@InjectMocks
ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

@Test
void someTest() {
    final Object object = new Object();
    when(dependency.method(anyString()))
        .thenReturn(Mono.error(new Exception()))
        .thenReturn(Mono.error(new Exception()))
        .thenReturn(Mono.error(new Exception()))
        .thenReturn(Mono.just(object));

    StepVerifier.create(classUnderTest.method("abc"))
        .expectNext(object)
        .verifyComplete();

    verify(dependency, times(4)).method("abc");
}
```

The above setup won't work as I figured out later, the retry in Reactor is not done via recalling the method for specific amount of time, but by calling the method once, gets the publisher, and re-subscribing to it again and again.

```java
class ClassUnderTest {
    private Dependency dependency;

    public Mono<Object> method(final String str) {
        return this.dependency.method(str).retryWhen(Retry.max(3));
    }
}
```

And re-subscribing **won't** work, if the `Dependency#method` is implemented as:

```java
class Dependency {
    private OtherDependency otherDependency;

    public Mono<Object> method(final String str) {
        return this.otherDependency.get(str).map(/* some mapping logic */);
    }
}
```

`Dependency#method` cannot make too much assumption on whether or not `OtherDependency#get` is deferred. Hence, `Dependency` needs to:

```java
class Dependency {
    private OtherDependency otherDependency;

    public Mono<Object> method(final String str) {
        return Mono.defer(() -> this.otherDependency.get(str)).map(/* some mapping logic */);
    }
}
```

Since we want to say that each method should be "retry-able", does that mean, we need to **always** use `defer(...)`?

Or am I mis-understanding anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have thought about it.

The easier way instead of making all methods natively "retry-able", is to wrap the publisher with `defer` before attaching the `retryWhen` operator.

Before:

```java
class ClassUnderTest {
    private Dependency dependency;

    public Mono<Object> method(final String str) {
        return dependency.method(str).retryWhen(Retry.max(3));
    }
}
```

After:

```java
class ClassUnderTest {
    private Dependency dependency;

    public Mono<Object> method(final String str) {
        return Mono.defer(() -> dependency.method(str)).retryWhen(Retry.max(3));
    }
}
```

Now, we do not have to say all methods should be natively "retry-able", but to always wrap the to-be-retried publisher with `defer`.

Comment: that works, but when writing your own Mono-returning method you should favor returning a cold publisher when possible, ie one that re-trigger the data generation for each subscription, for example your deferred one. cold is the default go-to, hot the exception I'd say.

Comment: Hi @SimonBaslé! Thanks for commenting. I am new to reactive programming. In my early reading of the Project Reactor's reference I could not find general best practices on hot vs cold publishers and when and when not to use `defer()`. So am I right that, I should use `defer()` or `fromSupplier()` or other variants whenever possible when calling a method of a dependency?